# Upgrading Magnento/Patching

Tags: magento, upgrade, patch

First - does upgrading also patch?

Second - this is the main problem area, last time I tried upgrading magnento through the /downloader I lost my entire site and had to start from square one.

Most of my files are currently at the 1.9.1.1 version - and are needing to be upgraded to 1.9.2 - is there a specific order which these need to be upgraded in? What is the most efficient and effective way to get those upgrades on there.

Patching - We had our host dev try and patch our site with the SUPEE-6285 and he butchered that.. Any patches we try to do in addition to it now are useless and have no effect on our site. Is there a way to remove that patch and patch the with the newest one - being SUPEE-6482

Comment: Lost everything? ALWAYS backup before performing any kind of upgrade or patch for this reason.

Comment: That lesson has been learned the hard way. It wasn't so much that I lost the actual files - something was corrupted between the files and the database, couldn't access any of the magento backend, and the site itself essentially just reverted to just an index of directories. Decided it'd be easier to just start fresh with a new magento install and everything since we would have still had to upgrade everything even if we did manage to save the site on the first time around.

Answer (score 2):

About your first question: Yes.

About second one: always create a backup before updating and patching, and before test on a testing server never try to upgrade your shop on production server because there might be some extensions conflict.

And yes there is a specific order about patch files, if you want install all of them. because sometimes some of them are required to install a specific patch.

To revert an installed patch use this command:

```
sh patch-file-name.sh -R
```

To check installed patches history, check `applied.patches.list` located in `app/etc/`

For more information and to learn how to install and revert a patch check these links out:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html

https://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/Installing-a-Patch-for-Magento-Community-Edition.pdf